# Pre-create all main views

Tags: javascript, mobile, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Our application has about 30 page. Does it make sense create all view page without data when application launch? Or better create page when it necessary. What about performance, responsiveness of the interface on mobile device? 
Yes, it looks crazy create 30 page with full content, but  we can create not whole page, but  create only  base structure of page(container for page content). When page displaying, then fill it content. Maybe it will do  transitions between page more smoothly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, don't do it!

You should actually try to minimize the DOM the mobile (especially) browser has to handle, and filling the DOM with 30-pages will most likely be a nightmare for it to handle (depending on complexity of each page of course).

I'm not really sure what you mean by this sentance:

> In first option view(list, dataview) can be connected with store and will be updating automaticaly, when store load.

Could you elaborate?

Comment: Yes, if create all views with their full structure and data it bad idea. But if we create view without content only container? About list i create separate questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12560159/update-list-dom-only-if-list-displayed

Comment: You will still fill your DOM with unnecessary elements, and if you still have to fill the views with data I can't imagine that the time to create a few extra elements for a view would be that much of a hurdle, and thus not that time consuming compared to filling them from the store.

In an application I have I am actually removing view that are not needed, just to increase responsiveness of the app.